# AS3 Fla File converted from AS2 not showing code in IntelliJ-Idea

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, intellij-idea, air, actionscript-2

I exported an Fla containing AS2 code to AS3 and generated an SWF that is supposed to contain the required object oriented codes.But after i added it to ***IntelliJ IDE*** and  double clicking, i do not get any inner files.Nor im able to call any instances.What is going wrong here?

UPDATE:

My colleague tells me that if we drag and drop the exported swf into intellij we dont get any button names and stuff to work upon in the action script if its AS2.So he sets AS3 and exports the swf.It worked for other files when it comes to this file upon dragging and dropping it into intellij we don't get any button names to work upon. That is the problem

This is an example of a working swf upon clicking the swf
we get the fla folder and upon clicking on hg_11 or any of the sub files we are able to get the names of the buttons.But when clicking on the file im talking about nothing comes up.BTW ***I just started using IntelliJ and Flash today im a total noob in this stuff***.The thing is the they want this animation with interactivity running on Android Devices.I just need to link 1 SWF to another on Click of a Button.

[image]

Comment: Are you working Flash IDE and IntelliJ together? And _...double clicking, I do not get any inner files._ is this output `swf` or `as` file?

Comment: @coner Can you please see my comment on the answer below.

Comment: Please edit your question. This is not what you are asking.

Comment: I dont have access to the build machine now.I will post a screenshot and edit the question tomorrow.

Comment: @techno You question is unclear. You can (maybe) compile (get an SWF file) an AS2 code as AS3 without getting errors by disabling the `strict` and `warnings` modes but normally the SWF will not work. Try to put that supposed AS2 code maybe it's AS3 one, or maybe there is no AS2 code at all ... also what do you mean by "*I added it to IntelliJ IDE*", did you mean importing the SWF, loading it by code ... are you trying to get some assets from the SWF ? Try to explain more the situation ...

Comment: @akmozo Please see the update.

Comment: @coner Please see the update.

Comment: Ok this was misleading and your question does not represent your problem at all.

Comment: @BotMaster ...okay.. what should i do

Comment: @techno I tried what you are talking about and I remarked that IntelliJ IDEA can just decompile AS3 (Flash) apps. So I think that your "not" working SWF is really an AS2 app but the other ones were AS3 apps. This is just my guess, I can't confirm anything about that, but try to verify your SWFs, maybe that's the real problem.

Comment: @akmozo Thanks i will check and get back.

Comment: @akmozo The file is SWF format only.I just copy the the file and paste it in the src folder.It seems the IDE can decompile it.But in the case of the file i told you,it cannot.

Answer (score 1):

You are not reporting something that is possible.

When you say "I exported an Fla containing AS2 code to AS3" and then "that is supposed to contain the required object oriented codes".

It seems that you are somehow expecting a code conversion from AS2 to AS3 but that's just impossible. When you convert a former AS2 based .fla to a AS3 based .fla the conversion gets rid of all AS2 code and that's the end of it. It's not gonna write or convert anything to AS3 because that's just impossible to do automatically since those 2 languages are too different.

There's no such thing as automatic code conversion from as2 to as3. The only thing that could happen with a AS2 project is that the new AS3 based .fla file gets rid of every single line of AS2 code.

So your question can safely be removed since it is based on the idea that something magical happens inside .fla files and old AS2 code gets transformed into new and shinny AS3 code. It does not happen and it will never happen.

Comment: I think you misunderstood.we have an Fla file.When its open in flash it shows as2 in the tool bar.I'm a noob when it comes to flash.My colleague tells me that if we drag and drop the exported swf into intellij we dont get any button names and stuff to work upon in the action script if its AS2.So he sets AS3 and exports the swf.It worked for other files when it comes to this file upon dragging and dropping it into intellij we don't get any button names to work upon. That is the problem.

Comment: But you are talking about inner files. Why would there be any? Also you cannot compile a swf with as2 code inside if you set it to as3, you'll get a bunch of error and no valid swf will be generated.

Comment: I dont have access to the build machine now.I will post a screenshot tomorrow.